# javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call

Tags: bean-validation

`@size(max =241)` is given for string validation and if the string length is less than `112` characters the validation is passing but if it is more than `112` then it is throwing exception :

> javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during >isValid call.

How should i fix it ?

Comment: Could you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: Here you can find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69098017/14547085

Answer (score 0):

I was using hibernate-validator-4.3.0-Final.jar for email validation, there was a bug in when handling large string, hence it was throwing the error, once updated the jar file.hibernate-validator-4.3.2-Final.jar this fixed.