# HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa

I created a custom validation rule to check if a username exists in the database.

My User class has a username that has a custom validation rule that when an object is created it checks in the database if that same username exists.

I use an `interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>` to save the users to the database and in the custom validation rule to check if the username already exists. I make use of

```
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;
```

Separately I can validate users and save them to the database, but when using them together like calling `userRepository.save(user);` the `@Autowired UserRepository userRepository;` in the custom validation rule does not get initiated so it remains null.

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
```

**Custom validation rule**

```
public class UsernameConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Username, String> {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return !userRepository.existsUserByUsername(s);
    }
}
```

**Trying to save user in the controller**

```
  @PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user,BindingResult result, @RequestParam String password2){

        if(result.hasErrors()) return "register";

       userRepository.save(user);
               
        return "login";
    }
```

[image: An illustration of my problem]

- Here is the full stack trace: https://justpaste.it/7rnx7
- Here is the full project: https://github.com/leotrimvojvoda/todo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none` in *application.propperties*

I found the answer in this thread: [Spring-Boot How to properly inject javax.validation.Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604540/spring-boot-how-to-properly-inject-javax-validation-validator/23615478#23615478)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615478/14547085) answer includes the solution to the problem that I was having with bean validation and hibernate.

*"...because Hibernate doesn't know about the Spring Context and as far as I can tell there is no way to tell it, not even with the LocalValidatorFactoryBean. This causes the Validator's to run twice. One correctly, and once that fails."*

In short the solution is to tell hibernate to not run the validation by adding the following line in your *application.propperties*

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
```

I suggest you read the full answer of this question to better understand it's implications with *LocalValidatorFactoryBean*.

Credits also go to [João Dias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16572295/jo%C3%A3o-dias) for helping me find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Custom Validation class does not seem a Spring managed bean. Try adding `@Component` annotation to it as follows:

```java
@Component
public class UsernameConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Username, String> {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return !userRepository.existsUserByUsername(s);
    }
}
```

---

Update 06/09/2021
As it seems (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361762/16572295) you also need to setup a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to have this working:

```java
@Bean
public Validator validatorFactory() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

Comment: I already did try that, but without success. I also tried to change the scope of the UserRepository to prototype, also no success.

Comment: So it seems that you need something else to have it working --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361762/16572295. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with LocalValidatorFactoryBean(), because the validation works perfectly. I think the problem might be in that Repository, because it's trying to start another process while one is already running, so the userRepo.save(user) is calling the userRepo.existsUserByUsername("username")

Comment: I am not that sure about `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` either to be honest. But I don't believe it has anything to do with `userRepo.save(user)`. Validation is done before the code reaches that point. And I also don't get the "validation works perfectly" when as you state in the question that "in the custom validation rule does not get initiated so it remains null".

Comment: Nevertheless, everywhere I look, I find stuff like: "In spring if we register `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` to bootstrap `javax.validation.ValidatorFactory` then custom `ConstraintValidator` classes are loaded as Spring Bean. That means we can have the benefit of Spring's dependency injection in validator classes." Which is basically what you are looking for.

Comment: This was not exactly what I was looking for, but it led me to more research about `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` that you said and I finally found the correct solution. So according to a stackoverflow answer (link below) _"...because Hibernate doesn't know about the Spring Context and as far as I can tell there is no way to tell it, not even with the `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`. **This causes the Validator's to run twice. One correctly, and once that fails.**"_

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23615478/14547085

Thanks for your help, the LocalValidatorFactoryBean was a good hint.