# Not able to inject dependency into ConstraintValidator implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, customvalidator

I have tried several methods to inject dependency into my `ConstraintValidator` implementation but nothing is working. I have tried almost all stackoverflow threads. I am using Hibernate Validator to achieve custom validation. I want `FileService` to be injected into `ApiMockResponseValidator`. I am sharing the things that I have tried.

1. Simple `@Autowired` annotation and constructor injection:

```
@Component
public class ApiMockResponseValidator
    implements ConstraintValidator<MockResponse, ApiMockResponse> {

  @Autowired
  FileService fileService;

  private boolean validate(....) {
     // logic
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(ApiMockResponse mockResponse, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    System.out.println("\n\n  --- " + fileService + " --- \n\n");  // remains null
    // validate()
  }
}
```

I have tried this by Constructor injection only and also by removing `@Component` but nothing works and the Validator is not instantiating. Simple `@Autowired` is not injecting dependency and constructor autowiring is giving

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: com.lendin.ib.utils.validator.ApiMockResponseValidator.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.privilegedactions.NewInstance.run(NewInstance.java:44)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.ApiMockResponseValidator.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
```

2. Creating `Validator` bean

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {


  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public Validator validator(AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {

    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure()
        .constraintValidatorFactory(
            new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory))
        .buildValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();

    return validator;
  }
}
```

Even after this `fileService` is null.

3. Tried creating `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @Autowired
  public Validator validator(final AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {
    new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory);
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean x = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    x.setConstraintValidatorFactory(
        new SpringConstraintValidatorFactory(autowireCapableBeanFactory));
    return x;
  }

}
```

This is also not helping and `fileService` is null.

Is there any way I can achieve injecting dependency?

I know that if `SpringConstraintValidatorFactory` can instantiate `ConstraintValidator` implementation and Hibernate can just use it rather then instantiating the implementation itself then it can work.

Comment: You do have a `FileService` Bean, don't you? Did you declare it in a `@Configuration`? Then you could use constructor injection and try to create the validator in the same config with `return new ApiMockResponseValidator(fileService())`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that the ConstraintValidator instance is created outside of Spring scope (maybe Hibernate does that), the dependency injection is not managed by Spring.

What you can do as a workaround, is create a `FileServiceHolder` as a singleton

```java
class FileServiceHolder {
   private static final FileServiceHolder INSTANCE = new FileServiceHolder();
   private FileService fileService;

   private FileServiceHolder() {
   }

   public static FileServiceHolder getInstance() {
      return INSTANCE;
   }

   @Autowired
   public setFileService(FileService fileService) {
      this.fileService = fileService;
   }
}
```

And in a `Configuration` class create a bean from that singleton

```java
@Configuration
class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   FileServiceHolder fileServiceHolder() {
      return FileServiceHolder.getInstance();
   }
}
```

Exposing the same object (singleton) as a bean, makes it possible for Spring to inject the dependencies. This is done through the setter method `setFileService`.

Now in your `Validator` class, you can access the `FileService` through the `FileServiceHolder`

```java
class Validator {
   boolean validate(....) {
      FileServiceHolder.getInstance().doStuff();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56557189/737587

In short, you need to explicitly tell Hibernate to use Spring's `LocalValidatorFactoryBean`. This can be done by setting a `javax.persistence` property, which in turn can be done using a `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` like so:

```
// To be added in a @Configuration class:

@Bean
@Lazy
public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator) {
    return (Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) -> {
        hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.factory", validator);
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it was solved adding this in application.properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
```

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072406/hv000028-unexpected-exception-during-isvalid-call)